# Displaying the selected color's code on top of the color tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to display the color's hex code that has been selected using the color tag.

If so how to achieve that.

Here's my code snippet:

```css
input
{
padding:0;
border:none; 
border-color:transparent;
height:40px; 
width:150px;
position:relative;
box-shadow:none;
}

span
{
position:absolute;
color:#fff;
left:20px;
padding-top:10px;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" name="color" value="#0a7ea4">
<span><!--I want the color name here--> color name</span>
```

Any scripts also can be used.

Is this possible by only using css and jquery?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `onchange` event listener, to set the value to the `span` element

```js
function getColorCode() {
  document.getElementById('color_name').innerHTML = event.currentTarget.value
}
```

```css
input  {
  padding:0;
  border:none; 
  border-color:transparent;
  height:40px; 
  width:150px;
  position:relative;
  box-shadow:none;
}
span {
  position:absolute;
  color:#fff;
  left:20px;
  padding-top:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<input id="input_color" type="color" onchange="getColorCode(event)" name="color" value="f025cb">
<span id="color_name"> color name</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign a class name to the `<span>` element and then set the value of the color to it using the class selector for class name you have added to `<span>`.

**using `jQuery`**

```js
$('.color-name').text($('[name="color"]').val());
```

```css
input {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-color: transparent;
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: none;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="color" name="color" value="#0a7ea4">
<span class='color-name'></span>
```

**using `JavaScript`**

```js
var colorVal = document.querySelector('[name="color"]').value;
document.querySelector('.color-name').innerText = colorVal;
```

```css
input {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-color: transparent;
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: none;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" name="color" value="#0a7ea4">
<span class='color-name'></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = document.getElementById('color').value` - this line sets the default value.

The event is aware of when there is any change to change the span value.

```
document.getElementById('color').addEventListener('change', function (){
  document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = this.value;
});
```

```js
document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = document.getElementById('color').value

document.getElementById('color').addEventListener('change', function (){
  document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = this.value;
});
```

```css
input {
  padding:0;
  border:none; 
  border-color:transparent;
  height:40px; 
  width:150px;
  position:relative;
  box-shadow:none;
}

span {
  position:absolute;
  color:#fff;
  left:20px;
  padding-top:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" name="color" value="#0a7ea4" id="color">
<span></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for putting effort for my question, but McRist is the first one to answer so I have to accept his answer, I upvoted your answer. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var theInput = document.getElementById("color");
    var theColor = theInput.value;
    theInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
    document.getElementById("displaycolor").innerHTML = theInput.value + " HEX code";
    }, false);
```

```css
input
{
padding:0;
border:none; 
border-color:transparent;
height:40px; 
width:150px;
position:relative;
box-shadow:none;
}

span
{
position:absolute;
color:#fff;
left:20px;
padding-top:10px;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="color" name="color" value="f025cb"  >
<span id="displaycolor"><!--I want the color name here--> color name</span>
```

add the "id" in input to find by "getElementById", then use a listener or a function to work